# Getting Bus Error when trying to access size more than 4000 bytes through /dev/mem

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, mmap

Python /dev/mem application issue
Our project is to access the BRAM through socket application. I am trying to do read and write to BRAM through python /dev/mem file. i am getting Bus Error when i tried to access size more than 4000 bytes. and also i am not getting the proper API to write the data to BRAM.

I am expecting a proper /dev/mem application to perform Read Write operation to BRAM

My python code is as shown in the image

Read data from BRAM

```
base_addr = raddr
virt_base = base_addr & ~(mmap.PAGESIZE - 1)
virt_offset = base_addr - virt_base
length = size
mmap_file = os.open('/dev/mem', os.O_RDWR | os.O_SYNC)
mem = mmap.mmap(mmap_file, length + virt_offset, 
                mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_READ | 
                mmap.PROT_WRITE, offset=virt_base)
rdbuf = np.frombuffer(mem, np.uint32, length >> 2, virt_offset)
```

Write Data to BRAM

```
base_addr = 0xa0000000
virt_base = base_addr & ~(mmap.PAGESIZE - 1)
virt_offset = base_addr - virt_base
length = size
mmap_file = os.open('/dev/mem', os.O_RDWR | os.O_SYNC)
mem = mmap.mmap(mmap_file, length + virt_offset, 
                mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.PROT_READ | 
                mmap.PROT_WRITE, offset=virt_base)
array = np.frombuffer(mem, np.uint32, length >> 2, virt_offset)
array[0:length] = data
```

Regards,

Ram

Answer (score 0):

Happy to inform that i have solved the Bus error when accessing more than 4000 bytes of data using python /dev/mem application.
Firstly we need to reserve the complete BRAM in the DTS and make status of the BRAM to be dissabled.